# RoR app crashed, logs referrencing lots of different libraries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zsh

I used to do a lot of Ruby on Rails programming on bash but since changing over to robby russells zsh, I have not done any production level work.

I recently did a change and pushed it to heroku and I got this error when I checked heroku logs:

```
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557111+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `const_get'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557111+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `block in constantize'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557112+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `each'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557115+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `inject'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557118+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `constantize'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557136+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:583:in `get'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557144+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:614:in `constantize'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557145+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise.rb:320:in `get'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557148+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557149+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557149+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557152+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557167+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557167+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise.rb:350:in `new'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557168+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise.rb:350:in `add_mapping'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557170+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557184+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557184+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557196+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/routes.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557199+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:436:in `instance_exec'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557199+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:436:in `eval_block'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557202+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.6.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:418:in `draw'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557217+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557217+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557220+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557222+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557236+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557236+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `block in load_paths'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557239+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `each'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557242+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `load_paths'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557256+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:18:in `reload!'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557256+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `reload_routes!'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557270+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/rails.rb:17:in `block in <class:Engine>'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557277+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `block in execute_hook'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557280+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557281+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557283+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:50:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557301+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `each'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557301+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.6.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:49:in `run_load_hooks'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557304+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557305+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557307+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557321+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557321+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557324+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557326+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557340+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557346+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557349+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557350+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557350+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557364+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557364+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557367+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557369+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557388+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `require_relative'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557389+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557392+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557392+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557400+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `new'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557402+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `<main>'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557405+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557407+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557422+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557423+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557426+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557428+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557441+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557442+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557444+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:44:in `start'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557450+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557452+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557455+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557469+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557470+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557473+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557475+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557489+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557489+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.6.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557492+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.557494+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2020-04-07T01:51:58.563811+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2020-04-07T01:51:58.563812+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.6.2 application starting in production
2020-04-07T01:51:58.563813+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2020-04-07T01:51:58.563813+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2020-04-07T02:36:56.635446+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/robots.txt" host=dancortes-portfolio.herokuapp.com request_id=d7acd72b-3465-4461-b067-0f51f55a289e fwd="77.88.5.192" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Prior to the app crashing once pushing to Heroku, I saw various warnings, one about Procfile missing, which I have never had, another about the ruby version being outdated. Could this mean I need to update my ruby version?

Comment: I don't see any connection whatsoever between that error message and RVM or ZSH. Your rails app crashed and looking at the logs will tell you why.

Comment: @max, what you see above is the logs.

Comment: Yeah. Still don't get why you're jumping to the conclusion that it has anything to with RVM. Heroku does not use RVM. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

Comment: @max, prior to getting this crash, when I pushed to Heroku, I got a warning about ruby version being outdated and another warning about procfile missing, but I have never had a procfile. I did not think the error was related to RVM, but rather the ruby version being outdated and subsequently having problems updating because I use zsh whereas I used to use bash years ago when I first created this app.

Comment: Its possible that you previously had been deploying to a older version of the heroku stack. Your local shell/rvm is totally irrelevant to what is happening on heroku.

Comment: @max, hmm, after this error occurred I did do the heroku-18 upgrade from heroku-16, but its a migration that takes awhile and it's still awaiting heroku-18 migration.

Comment: You should be able to bump the ruby version to `2.6.6` after testing it locally - 2.4 is outdated. Rails pre 6.1 emits an insane amount of depreciation messages on Ruby 2.7- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#ruby-versions